# How to prove this Big O relation

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Consider the following question:

> Prove that $$\frac{x} { \log \log (x) - \log \log \log(x) } + {2}^{ \frac{x} { \log \log (x) } } = O \left(\small\frac{x} { \log \log(x) }\right)$$

It is clear that $\frac{x} { \log \log (x) - \log \log \log(x) }$ is O($\frac{x} { \log \log(x) })$.

I can't prove $ 2^{\frac{x} { \log \log x}} $  less than or equal to any constant as $\frac{x} { \log \log x} $ is neither increasing nor decreasing.

And I don't have any other argument in my mind. So, please help.

Comment: $x/\log\log x$ is increasing for $x\geqslant 6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously false: $2^y > C\, y$ for $y$ big enough and $x/\log\log x \to \infty$

Comment: I understand how for y big enough $2^y >Cy $ and $\frac{x} { log log x} \to \infty$. But I am unable to understand how it proves the statement false. Can you please explain?

Comment: Take any $C>0$. Then $2^y > C y$ for all $y\ge y_0$ for some $y_0$. Since $x/\log\log x \to \infty$, for $x$ big enough $x/\log\log x > y_0$ so  $2^{x/\log\log x} > C x/\log\log x$ . Hence $2^{x/\log\log x} \ne O(x/\log\log x)$